# React native fetch token and then get to user details using fetch api

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise

I am building login app using React native. For auth, I am using spring boot app.

Here is use case.

1. User visit to client's login screen and enters username and password.
2. React native send request to the server using fetch API.
3. If the token object comes back then login (username/password) are correct.
4. If the token is correct app should make another call to the server to get user details by token.

Problem is - how I can first API call to validate login and get token and once get the valid token to make another API call to get user details.

Here is the code:

```
import { dologin,getUser } from "../../API";
```

And Login handeler

```
handleLogin = () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state

    if (username.length == 0 || password.length == 0){
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: 'Login and password is required.',
          loginProcessing: false,
        });
    } else {

      this.setState({errorMessage: null});


      dologin(username, password).then(accessToken => {

        if(!accessToken.state){
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: accessToken.data,
            loginProcessing: false,
          });
          return null;
        } else{
          return accessToken.data;
        }
      });

    }
}
```

Fetch API

```
//get user by token
export const getUser = (token) => {
if(token == null) return null;
return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/user/get', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.json());
    return response.json();
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
}


export const dologin = (username, password) => {

  var details = {
     username: username,
     password: password,
     grant_type:'password'
 };

 var formBody = [];
  for (var property in details) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }


  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("enrecover:EsTEsBDETSEWAvAWcsI"),
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: formBody.join("&")
    }).then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200){
            return {status: true, data:res.json() }
        } else {
            return {status: false, data:"Invalid username or password." }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the  handleLogin async function and try this one

```js
handleLogin = async () => {
  const { username, password } = this.state

  if (username.length == 0 || password.length == 0) {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: 'Login and password is required.',
      loginProcessing: false,
    });
  } else {
    let loginResponse = await dologin(username, password);
    if (loginResponse.status) {
        // if loginResponse = {token: "tokenValue"}
        userDetails = await getUser(loginResponse.token);
        console.log("User Details",userDetails)
    } else {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: loginResponse.data,
        loginProcessing: false,
      });
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: question for you, why not go ahead and return the user data in the 'dologin' function? that would prevent you from having to take another trip to the server.